# Получить данные из локального JSON qt c++

Tags: c++, qt

Подскажите, как получить данные из локального JSON файла с помощью QT и С++.
Так же интересно, как из записывать обратно в файл.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/json.html

Comment: С помощью json парсера. В qt, ИМХО, очень уж неудобный парсер, так что я бы порекомендовал nlohmann_json

Comment: Присоединяюсь ко мнению Bearded Beave. nlohmann написал шикарную библиотеку для работы с json, и она header only, то есть подключается к проекту одним инклудом #include "json.hpp" из папки single_include